# Better way to give space other than &nbsp;

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, .net

I am using the following code to give blank space so that the three elements "label, then dropdown and then a button for action on dropdown" are right aligned in a panel in a web page.

Now, I know I can do with padding/margin, however, it all works only with respect to the element at right side and not from the right hand side of the browser.

However, I was talented enough to achieve what I want using `&nbsp;` but I find it weird to write the code this way:

```
 LiteralSpecial.Text = "&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;" + 
            "&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;" +
            "&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;" +
                "&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;" +
                    "&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;" +
                        "&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;" +
                         "&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;" +
                          "&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;" +
                           "&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;" +
                            "&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;" +
                             "&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;" +
           "Select page  ";
```

Is there are way to refine this please, folks?

Comment: are you familiar with the `new string()` method overloads.. for example if you want 15 spaces ..then you could do `var charSpaces = new string(' ' ,15)`

Comment: I wonder what happens if you re-size the browser.

Comment: "talented enough" eh?

Comment: there is absolutely a better way, but it involves css, not `&nbsp;` and we would need to see the resulting html. As @Arkamis pointed out, have you resized your browser to see how your current solution almost certainly breaks?

Comment: @DJKRAZE: Sorry it didn't work.

Comment: @TyCobb:Sorry it didn't work.

Comment: @ethorn10: Mate, sadly your suggestions didn't earned anything when I tested.

Comment: @Divine my suggestion was just to consider using css. If you need help with that, post the relevant html (not the `LiteralSpecial`) and I'm sure it can be achieved.

Comment: @ethorn10: I am not sure, I think we can achieve with Div, didn't try though. But it adds a section which I don't want

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using CSS?

```
<div style="text-align:right">Select page</div>
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/vhxchyrj/2/

Comment: It's difficult to know what you intend without a little more context. I could help you better if you posted some more HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width:600px;padding-left:550px;">Select page</div>
```